# fix section and item bullets size

Tags: beamer

I would like to fix the size of `\item` as big as `\section`. Many thanks in advance.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    
\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
    \frame<beamer>{ 
        \frametitle{Outline}   
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection] 
    }
}
%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents{}  
\end{frame}

\section{Chapter 1}
\subsection{\textcolor{black}{General Introduction.}}
%\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}

\begin{frame}{Overview \& Contributions}
    \begin{enumerate} %\begin{enumerate}
        \item \textcolor{red}{Chapter 2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Chapter 2 contributes
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate} %\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the `itemize subitem` template like this (I assume with `section` you actually mean a subsection because you call your sections chapters ...):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
    
\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
    \frame<beamer>{ 
        \frametitle{Outline}   
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection] 
    }
}


\makeatletter 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raise0.2ex\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}  
\makeatother

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents{}  
\end{frame}

\section{Chapter 1}
\subsection{\textcolor{black}{General Introduction.}}
%\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}

\begin{frame}{Overview \& Contributions}
    \begin{enumerate} %\begin{enumerate}
        \item \textcolor{red}{Chapter 2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Chapter 2 contributes
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate} %\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]